# Return most results for a match based on a preferential order of keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have built a program to index keywords in text files and put them to the database.

My tables are simple:

```
FILE_ID|Name
------------
1      | a.txt
2      | b.txt
3      | c.txt

KEYWORD_ID|FILE_ID|Hits
-----------------------
1         | 1     | 55
2         | 1     | 10
3         | 1     | 88
1         | 2     | 44
2         | 2     | 15
1         | 3     | 199
2         | 3     | 1
3         | 3     | 4
```

There is no primary key in this table. I didn't find it necessary.

Now I'd like to search which file has most hits to certain keywords.

If I have only one keyword it is easy:

```
select top 10 * 
from words 
where keyword_id=1
order by hits desc
```

Lets say I want to search for files with keyword 1 and 3 (both must be present and first keyword has highest importance). After many hours I came with this:

```
select top 10 k.* 
from 
(
   select file_id, 
     max(hits) as maxhits 
   from words 
   where keyword_id=3 
   group by file_id
) as x 
inner join keyword as k 
  on (k.file_id = x.file_id 
      and k.keyword=1) 
order by k.hits desc
```

How to make this right? Especially if I want to search with N keywords. Would it be better use temp table and work with that?

If searching with keyword 1 and 3 I want FILE_ID 3 and 1 returned, in this order (because file_id 3 has higher hit count for keyword 1)

Comment: Based sample data in your question, what is expected output if `search for files with keyword 1 and 3` ?

Comment: If searching with keyword 1 and 3 I want FILE_ID 3 and 1 returned, in this order (because file_id 3 has higher hit count for keyword 1).

Comment: @itix please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but (based on your comment)  may be this is what you need ?

(I used table declaration from @scsimon answer)

```
declare @words table (KEYWORD_ID int, [FILE_ID] int, HITS int)
insert into @words
values
(1,1,55),
(2,1,10),
(3,1,88),
(1,2,44),
(2,2,15),
(1,3,199),
(2,3,1),
(3,3,4)

select [FILE_ID] from (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by KEYWORD_ID order by HITS desc) rn from @words
    where KEYWORD_ID in(1,3)
)t
where rn = 1
order by hits desc
```

Comment: This does what I asked and with *rn* in where clause it is possible sort results by secondary (or tertiary and so on...) keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all relevant keywords to be found are stored in table `KTable` which has two columns `ID` and `KEYWORD_ID`

Then query should be

```
SELECT 
   FileID,
   SUM(Hits) NetHits,
   SUM(Hits/K.ID) WeightedHits
FROM
   Words w JOIN Ktable K 
    on w.KEYWORD_ID= K.KEYWORD_ID
GROUP BY FileID
HAVING count(1) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Ktable )
ORDER BY 2 DESC,3 DESC
```

Same query using Windowing function will be

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
FileID,
NetHitsPerFile 
FROM 
(
SELECT 
   FileID,
   SUM(Hits) OVER (PARTITION BY FileID ORDER BY K.ID ASC) NetHitsPerFile,
   SUM(FileID) OVER(PARTITION BY K.ID) Files,
   SUM(Hits/K.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY FileID ORDER BY K.ID ASC) weightedHits

FROM
   Words w JOIN Ktable K 
    on w.KEYWORD_ID= K.KEYWORD_ID
)T
   WHERE Files= (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Ktable)
   ORDER BY NetHitsPerFile, weightedHits
```

Comment: This one I like. I created temporary table *declare @ktable table (ID float, KEYWORD_ID int)* where keywords are stored for query and this helps a lot.

Comment: Your latter example does not work though: it is not returning any results. Clause *WHERE Files= (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Ktable)* is not working as intended...

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way... if you only want to see the rows with the `KEYWORD_ID` you specify, just add that `WHERE CLAUSE` at the bottom as well. The `INNER JOIN` limits the `FILE_ID` to those which contain **both** `KEYWORD_ID` you specify by checking that the distinct count is = to the number of keywords. Thus, in the below example we limit the result set on 2 `KEYWORD_ID` and check to make sure each `FILE_ID` has 2 distinct `KEYWORD_ID` associated, with the `HAVING` clause

```
declare @words table (KEYWORD_ID int, [FILE_ID] int, HITS int)
insert into @words
values
(1,1,55),
(2,1,10),
(3,1,88),
(1,2,44),
(2,2,15),
(1,3,199),
(2,3,1),
(3,3,4)

select top 10 w.* 
from @words w
inner join
    (select [FILE_ID]
    from @words
    where KEYWORD_ID in (1,3)
    group by [FILE_ID]
    having count(distinct KEYWORD_ID) = 2
    ) x on x.[FILE_ID] = w.[FILE_ID]
order by HITS desc
```

Comment: Ah, actually there is one small issue: it should prefer keyword order. @DhruvJoshi gave me an idea how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use top (n) with ties for your query as below:

```
declare @n int = 10 --10 in your scenario
select top (@n) with ties *
from (
    select w.*, f.name from #words w inner join #files f
        on w.[FILE_ID] = f.[file_id]
    ) a 
    order by (row_number() over (partition by a.[file_id] order by hits desc)-1)/@n +1
```

Comment: This is counting all keywords. I have to limit query to count only specified keywords.